# I need to copy format and values from a partial row to a destination in a different sheet (same spreadsheet), function chaining problems?

Tags: google-apps-script, copy, range, copy-paste, typeerror

Trying to copy a partial range in a row using the getActiveRange() & getRow() AND getRange() with a specified range. I have data from a larger spreadsheet "Listings" that needs to be transferred from (getRowIndex, column 4, 1 row tall, 5 columns wide) to the next sheet "ProgressReport" starting under a frozen header. I need to add a row above row 4 in the "ProgressReport" sheet, then paste the format and values from the defined range in the "Listings" sheet. I keep getting a "TypeError" due to either the getRange() or getActiveRange() being "of null". I have checked to see whether or not the range functions have data in the active cells. I have found one answer that seems that it may be pointing me in the right direction by saying that there could be an error because I am using both getActiveRange() & getRow() functions chained together, but I have tried manipulating them so many ways that I simply can't figure it out.
ANY help would and I would be SO grateful!! Thank you in advance! I'll be checking all night because this is bugging me so bad...

```
function onEdit() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //sheet
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Listings!'); //sheet
 var activeRange = sheet.getActiveRange().getRowIndex(); //range
   var pullRow = activeRange.getRowIndex(); //integer
   var copyFrom = activeRange.getRange(pullRow, 4, 1, 5);

 var targetSheet = ss.getSheet('ProgressReport!');
 var target = targetSheet.getRange(4, 1, 1, 5);
// where PREntry = First row under the frozen header

   targetSheet.insertRowsBefore(4, 1);
// This inserts 1 row after the first row (insertAfterRow#, #ofRows)

    pullFrom.copyTo(copyFrom, target);
// where (activeRange) = (edited row in listings)
}
```

I tried to go in and change it up from a different angle; I've gotten all of the way to the last line and there's a "TypeError: Cannot find function copyTo in object xyz" //where "xyz is just the test data that populates the cells I'm testing.
Here is the NEW code that I am trying:

```
function onEdit() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
var rowStart = range.getRowIndex();
// where getRow retrieves the entire row that has been edited and getRowIndex retrieves the integer for later getSheetValues (below)
  var rangeColumn = sheet.getRange("D5:H5");
  var columnStart = rangeColumn.getColumn();
  var activePartialRow = sheet.getSheetValues(rowStart, columnStart, 1, 5);
// where the partial row is defined by activePartialRow using the integers returned by "columnStart" & "rowStart" vars
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("ProgressReport");

   targetSheet.insertRowBefore(4);
// This inserts 1 row after the fourth row (insertAfterRow#, #ofRows)

var target = targetSheet.getRange(4, 1, 1, 5);
// where the target is the first row under the frozen header

   activePartialRow.copyTo(target);
// where (activeRange) = (edited row in listings)
}
```

If anyone can offer an answer to this problem, I'd be extremely grateful! I've searched online, but just can't seem to find anything with what I'm searching! THANK YOU so much in advance! -JH

Comment: When you try do make a get range in a row that has never been with values you get these type error. Please check the number of rows before checking this. You can also use appendRow instead of copyTo

Comment: Ok "br araujo", so if I understand you correctly, I need to populate the cells of interest with information first, then run the script after changing it to append row (so that I can erase the line where I insert a row at the top) and the script should run fine after that?

Comment: yep, that's it. Just add the rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change this line in your code :

```
  var activePartialRow = sheet.getRange(rowStart, columnStart, 1, 5);
  // use getRange because we want to get a range object for copyTo()
```

but apart from that your code could be simplified a bit...

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var rowStart = range.getRowIndex();
  // where getRow retrieves the entire row that has been edited and getRowIndex retrieves the integer for later getSheetValues (below)
  var activePartialRow = sheet.getRange(rowStart, 4, 1, 5);// use getRange because we want to get a range object for copyTo()
  // where the partial row is defined by activePartialRow using the integers returned by "columnStart" & "rowStart" vars
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("ProgressReport");

  targetSheet.insertRowBefore(4);
  // This inserts 1 row after the fourth row (insertAfterRow#, #ofRows)

  var target = targetSheet.getRange(4, 1, 1, 5);
  // where the target is the first row under the frozen header

  activePartialRow.copyTo(target);
  // where (activeRange) = (edited row in listings)
}
```

Comment: thanks so much! I actually fixed it by doing appendRow(rowContents) followed by a descending time sort of the date column. But now I'm going to change this back because if someone puts the wrong date it wouldn't catch the mistake with the column sorry and I'd be sifting through everything to find it. Thanks again and I'll edit this post if the solution doesn't work! Merry Christmas!

Comment: this worked perfectly! I guess the problem was, like you said, I didn't correctly define the range being copied in my original line of code.